# How to Obviate Two Problems Resulting from a Minipage Overflow

Tags: page-breaking, minipage, overflow

When the contents of a minipage exceed the page capacity, (1) a leading blank page is automatically inserted; and (2) the overflow contents of the minipage descend into oblivion rather than break onto the following page.

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{4.5in}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

QUESTION: How may I modify the above code so that the contents of the minipage automatically break onto the following page, and thus (hopefully), do not cause a blank page to occur immediately prior to the page containing the minipage?

Thank you.

*Note:* Before posting this question, I checked to see what had been asked in the past, and it seems that a tcolorbox was involved---which is not the case here. I hope it's O.K. to post this question.

Comment: Minipages make unbreakable boxes.  I take it you want to change the margins, like in the quotation environment.

Comment: @John Kormylo I didn't intend for the (side) margins to change. I was hoping that it would be possible for the contents of the minipage to carry-over to the next page in the same manner as an ordinary paragraph does when it reaches the bottom of the page.

Comment: Sorry, unbreakable boxes cannot be broken, not even using \vsplit.  So the question is, why do you want to use a minipage?

Comment: @John Kormylo Initially, the minipages I used did not contain too much text. However, later,when I inserted too much text, the problem I described occurred. Since I couldn't fix it, and couldn't find an answer, I figured I'd post a question. Based on your comments, it appears that I must do something different. Thank you.